# Volley in android does not work anymore...?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to write some android code a bit more clearly (avoiding in-class definitions) but I stumbled upon a problem with volley described e.g. [here](http://griosf.github.io/android-volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.html), which does not seem to work! First, here is my code piece:

```
public class ServiceStock {

    public Context context;

    private class ResponseListener implements Response.Listener<String>  {

        ResponseListener() {
            Log.d("test Listener", "constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("test Listener:", response);
        }

    }

    private class ErrListener implements Response.ErrorListener  {

        public Context context;

        ErrListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Log.d("error Listener", "constructor");
        }


        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Did not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("error Listener", "error");
        }


    }

    public ServiceStock(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getCurrentStockPrice(String symbol) {
        Log.d("ServiceTest", "method_start");
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);
        String url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + symbol + "&f=sl1";

        ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener();
        ErrListener error = new ErrListener(this.context);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                listener,
                error
        );
        Log.d("ServiceTest", "method_end");

        return "OK";

    }
}
```

As one can see, I am writing to the log file. I see the following output:

```
0 20:01:54.215 3299-3299/com.impyiablue.stoxx D/ServiceTest: method_start
12-10 20:01:54.229 3299-3299/com.impyiablue.stoxx D/test Listener: constructor
12-10 20:01:54.229 3299-3299/com.impyiablue.stoxx D/error Listener: constructor
12-10 20:01:54.238 3299-3299/com.impyiablue.stoxx D/ServiceTest: method_end
```

but nothing else. I do not see log output when either the `listener` or the `error` instance is used. But on of them HAS TO BE USED!! At least it was working when I used in-class definition. But now neither `onResponse` nor `onErrorResponse` is being called!? So what is going on and how to fix it?

P.S.: Maybe someone has an idea on how to make the `context` handling a bit more complicated? Ha...

Comment: do you need to start.trigger request also? you are just creating stringRequest but not executing it!! Not even adding it in request queue?

Comment: Did u add the your request to volley RequestQueue ?

Comment: Oh, I overlooked this ridiculous senseless and confusing and stupid queue-adding thing! Now its working!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Volley in android does not work anymore…?

*It does work if implemented correctly.*

**Here is the problem in your code.**

You are just creating **stringRequest** but not executing it!! Not even adding it in **requestQueue**?

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this/*ActivityContext*/);
queue.add(stringRequest); // you need something like this.
```

**Here is simple request [tutorial link](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) for you.**

This is more common mistake in volley implementation people do.

Answer (score 2):

you missed to add stringRequest into queue

```
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I overlooked. Why make it easy in android if you can make it insanely complicated!